# How to get asterisk pattern one after another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-for-loop

I want to print two patterns in the same program but one in front of the other like this:

[image]

I have written the rest of the code but my pattern is indented normally:

```
x = input("Please enter any number: ")

for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,5):
        print('*', end="")
    print()

print("\n")
for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,5):
        if (i==0 or i==5-1 or j==0 or j==5-1):
            print('*', end='')
        else:
            print(' ', end= '')
    print()
```

My output:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print` statements are not sequential. You are first creating

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

Then

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

But you need to create each row at the same time.

**How it is working**

Print `*` `x` number of times. In the same row give a space  . Then print `*****` or `*    *` depending on whether it is the first or the last row. `('*' if i in [0, x-1] else ' ')*(x-2)` is checking the condition for the same.

```py
x = int(input("Please enter any number: "))
for i in range(x):
    print('*'*x + ' ' + '*' + ('*' if i in [0, x-1] else ' ')*(x-2) + '*')
```

```
***** *****
***** *   *
***** *   *
***** *   *
***** *****
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that in the first and last lines, you have to create the following:

```
***** *****
```

In the 2nd to (n-1)th lines, you know you have to format it as such:

```
***** *   *
```

I think you should be able to modify your code as needed with this knowledge.